# using a While Loop in batch file with sql

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I am new to Batch.

My code:

```
    @ECHO OFF

    SET colu=
    SET sn=
    SET /P colu= Enter column name:
    SET /P sn= Enter ID : 

     sqlcmd -U USER -P PWORD -S SERVER -d DBNAME-i sqlSCRIPT.sql -o LOG.txt -v delete=%colu% d_id=%%I

    pause

 SET /P sn= Enter ID :
     sqlcmd -U USER -P PWORD -S SERVER -d DBNAME-i sqlSCRIPT.sql -o LOG.txt -v delete=%colu% d_id=%%I

pause

 SET /P sn= Enter ID :
     sqlcmd -U USER -P PWORD -S SERVER -d DBNAME-i sqlSCRIPT.sql -o LOG.txt -v delete=%colu% d_id=%%I
```

The code works and does what I need it to do which is delete records from the db but I was hoping that there was a more efficient way to write it.

**How would I implement a while loop in batch that will keep asking the user to enter the id until they press the end key?** Also I realize that having **pause** in between sqlcmd is highly inconvenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

SET /P "colu=Enter column name:"

:Prompt
REM Clear any existing values.
SET "sn="

ECHO Enter a blank value to stop the operation.
SET /P "sn=Enter ID:"

REM Check for exist conditions.
IF "%colu%"=="" GOTO :EOF
IF "%sn%"=="" GOTO :EOF

REM If we get here, data was entered for both
sqlcmd -U USER -P PWORD -S SERVER -d DBNAME-i sqlSCRIPT.sql -o LOG.txt -v delete=%colu% d_id=%sn%
ECHO.
ECHO.

REM Ask again.
GOTO Prompt

:EOF
ENDLOCAL
```

This will keep prompting until you enter a blank value for either `colu` or `sn`. Also, I noticed you are using `%%I` in your SQL statement - I think you meant to use `%sn%` instead.

Comment: Thanks!! This was very helpful.